# How to tactfully follow up with informal job offer from a few months ago

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, internship, internal-transfer

Since May of 2018 I've been a college intern at a company. Last summer (May - September) and winter (December and January) I worked on a development team. This was not the team I was originally hired for, but due to some conflicts outside of anyone's control, I was there until I started again this May.

At the end of my time with the first team in December the manager I worked under said that if I wanted a job with his team, he would be happy to have me on the team.

I started the with the new team this May, and while I enjoy it, I also enjoyed working on the other team, It's different work, both with their pros and cons.

I'm not sure how to approach the other manager in a way that does not seem too forward. I do really want to start some kind of conversation with him about the subject.

Edit: I will be done school May 2020, I should also make it clear that It's very (95% of senior interns) receive a job offer before the end of August.

Comment: Yes. I'm a senior in college in case there was any confusion.

Comment: These are two jobs at the same company?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure how to approach the other manager in a way that does not
>   seem too forward. I do really want to start some kind of conversation
>   with him about the subject.
>
> Edit: I will be done school May 2020

In my experience, it's too early to talk about a job offer. But if your experience, in your domain and locale indicates otherwise, and if you actually want to commit to a Spring job now, then pursue it now.

Follow up with a thank you letter. Mention that you really liked working there. And say that you would like to talk about a job with his company. Try to show a lot of enthusiasm.

Ask when he thinks would be a good time to discuss that.

Only do this if you are serious about getting an offer and working there.

Answer (score 0):

**Let both your current and previous managers know about your desire to move back to your old team.**

Both managers can help you think through your feelings about your previous and current teams. You should expect them both to have your best interests in mind and want to help you find a great place to start your career. Be honest about what you are experiencing and listen to their advice and interpretations.

You will have different relationships with every team that you work on. Your managers will have had feelings similar to yours about their previous teams and can be excellent thought-partners as you process your own feelings and experience.